# VS Code Selenium Issue :

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Issue is seen in selenium, selenium module not found even after installation of selenium via pip.

I have already installed pip in windows (global). It is working in Pycharm and other apps.

*Driver Fine
working fine in Pycharm.*

**# Importing Selenium**

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
```

**# Terminal :**

```
PS C:\Users\sudip neupane> pip3 install selenium
***Requirement already satisfied: selenium in c:\users\sudip*** neupane\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (3.141.0)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3 in c:\users\sudip neupane\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from selenium) (1.26.5)
PS C:\Users\sudip neupane>
```

**# ERROR**

```
from selenium import webdriver
ModuleNotFoundError: ***No module named 'selenium***'
```

---

[image]

Comment: Do you also have a driver and a server installed for selenium? https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html#drivers

Comment: Yes !
its running in Pycharm and running via terminal in PC..

Issue only seen on VS Code.

Comment: In that case this is probably a problem with your language settings. Try setting the python interpreter to the same version you are using to run the code. ctrl+shift+p -> Python:Select Interpreter. If that is not working try Python: Build Workspace symbols. If all that fails you can also try to edit extraPaths in settings.json

Comment: no issue in interpreter and system. only selenium is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this issue was caused by having two python versions installed in my machine.

This worked after Reinstallation and Removing path from VS code while installing.

**this can be solved by :**

1. open file in VS Code and click **CTRL+SHIFT + P**
2. search -> Python: Select Interpreter
3. select any interpreter from list or and new Interpreter.
4. verify that selected interpreter have selenium modules.

Thanks!